# Spawn new process from within Postgres function

Tags: multithreading, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-8.3

Is it possible to spawn a new process to run a function from within a postgress function? Or am I limited to the originating request's one thread per db connection as per documentation?

The separate process is creating and populating a dynamically named table, is not returning any data, and is independant of the spawning function. On Postgresql 8.3.

Comment: You need upgrade to a current version. [8.3 is too old and unsupported by now.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Comment: @Erwin I agree totally, but isn't my call

Answer (score 2):

A procedural language should do the trick, e.g. an untrusted one such as [PL/PerlU](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl.html).

Other potential options include [Pl/Python, Pl/Ruby, Pl/SH...](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xplang.html).

Comment: I am using plpgsql. Will this not suffice?

Comment: SMan: not really... Postgres block until the query returns something. You want to run the query in a different pocess, and detach it so it doesn't die when its parent is done.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this.  if you spawn a separate process, it will mess up any transactional assumptions you have.  Do it all in the same process.  If you have to, look into Listen/Notify as a way of letting a separate daemon know to do work and note the NOTIFY will get raised on transaction commit.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to run an *asynchronous query* from within a PL/PgSQL procedure. If so, you can use `dblink` for this. Possibly even in the ancient and unsupported version you're running. See the manual; the function you want is [`dblink_send_query`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-dblink-send-query.html) from the `dblink` extension.

Keep in mind that any SQL you run that way will run in its own transaction. It'll commit or rollback independently of your main transaction, and it won't be able to see any uncommitted changes made by your main transaction.

It's often better to do this sort of thing from the client application.